# Ecto assoc_constraint doesn't work

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a `Review` model, which schema has `belongs_to` `User` notation.

Each review should belongs to user, so `user_id` column is mandatory.

```
  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
      |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
      |> a lot of things like validate_length
      |> assoc_constraint(:user)
  end
```

And  this is my migration:

```
defmodule MyReelty.Repo.Migrations.AddUserIdToReviews do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    alter table(:reviews) do
      add :user_id, references(:users, on_delete: :nothing)
    end
    create index(:reviews, [:user_id])
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, when I'm running

```
%Review{} |> Review.changeset(@valid_params) |> Repo.insert!
```

review is saved! I double checked there is no `user_id` or other user related information in details.

By the way, I checked another stuff like `validate_number` it works!

Why does `assoc_constraint` doesn't work in this case?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens"? What's the return value of `Repo.insert!`? Also, do you have `user_id` in `@required_fields`?

Comment: @Dogbert I edited the question.

Comment: @Dogbert thanks! I got the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `user_id` to `@required_fields`, that's it

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [doc](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#foreign_key_constraint/3), `cast_assoc` and `foreign_key_constraint` rely on the database to check if the foreign constraint is respected or not. In case the constraint is not respected, those functions convert the database error in a changeset error when you try to insert or update.

That is because you need the database to know if the foreign key is valid or not.

The foreign key constraint in only concerned by the fact that `user_id` references an existing user. If you try to insert a review containing a non existing `user_id`, the insertion will be rejected.

The fact that `user_id` should not be null is another subject. It depends if the `user_id` field is nullable. By default in Postgres, a field is nullable.

So, as you have noticed, inserting a review without a `user_id` is permitted.

If a review must have a related user, you can specify it in your migration.

```
add :user_id, references(:users, on_delete: :nothing), null: false
```

In the changeset function, you will use `validate_required` to check the field is not null, and `cast_assoc` to check it references an existing user.

Comment: Thanks @Istopopoki, helped me a lot to understand how it works under the hood. Appreciated!